# Is there something more efficient than For to solve thousands of similar numerical calculations?

Tags: performance-tuning, numerics

I have a really big vector (nearly 30,000 elements) called *x* and am trying to numerically find the root of a function where one of the parameters successively takes each value stored in the vector. At the moment, I'm using a `For` loop (I know a lot of people here cringe at the very mention of `For` loops for some reason; sorry):

```
For[j=1,j<=Length[x],j++,
 f = SOME REALLY COMPLICATED FUNCTION OF t AND x[[j]];
 sol[[j]]=t/.FindRoot[f,{t,t0}];
 Clear[t];
];
Print[sol];
```

I'm wondering whether there's a more efficient way of doing this (I'm talking code-wise, not things like some simple approximation to *f* which gives an acceptably small error). Currently, my code takes just over 5 minutes to run (I've got a few more operations before and after the numerical bit, but they don't take long, so perhaps the numerical bit takes 4-5 minutes). I've tried setting it up as a vector operation (see code below), but after about 10 minutes of evaluation I quit the kernel because it was clear to me that that wasn't going to be more efficient than the `For` loop. Here's my vector-operation code:

```
f = SOME REALLY COMPLICATED FUNCTION OF t AND x;
sol=t/.FindRoot[f,{t,t0}]
Print[sol];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: (a) People cringe because of [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18396#18396). (b) Consider parallelization, i.e. `sol=ParallelTable[t/.FindRoot[SOME REALLY COMPLICATED FUNCTION OF t AND x[[j]],{t,t0}],{j,Length[x]}]`. (c) Consider `Compile`.

Comment: Best bet would be to focus on different settings for `FindRoot` that might improve its performance. That is almost certainly where the bottleneck lies.

Comment: If the solutions working through the `x` vector are not far off from each other, use the last `t` as the start point for the next `FindRoot` iteration.

Comment: @yohbs Thanks! That reduces the time the code takes to run by a factor of about 2.5. That's exactly what I was looking for. :) What does Compile do and how do I use it?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I'm pretty sure I can't do any better with respect to `t0`. Is there anything else I can do to optimise it?

Comment: @MikeY That's a good suggestion, but all the solutions are within about 0.01 of `t0` (which is about 1.42), so I'm not sure setting each value of `t` as the starting point for the next `FindRoot` would make a big difference.

Comment: `Compile` [(link)](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Compile.html) does, as its name suggests, compilation. It takes a series of mathematica commands and compiles them to machine language which is more efficient in terms of running time. Two things: If this will do anything, it will probably mainly accelerate the `COMPLICATED FUNCTION` and not `FindRoot`, so if the bottleneck is in `FindRoot` I wouldn't bother. Second, [not all mathematica's commands are compilable](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/list-of-compilable-functions) so this might not work for you.

Comment: If you can take derivatives of `f`, you could recast the problem as an ODE, and then the output of `NDSolve` will give you an interpolating function that can be used on your vector.

Comment: @yohbs Thanks for the link. My bottleneck is definitely in `FindRoot`, so no point using `Compile`, then, but it's good to know there's that option.

Comment: @CarlWoll Thanks! I'll see whether that helps.